# Linear Algebra composition Can someone help ( Challenge Problem )

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $(V, K)$ and $φ, ψ : V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformations.

Furthermore, we define the bracket of $φ$ and $ψ$ as

$[φ, ψ] := φ ◦ ψ − ψ ◦ φ$.

We say that two linear transformations commute if

$[φ, ψ] = 0$,

where 0 is the zero map. Show that if $[φ, ψ]$ commutes with $φ$, then
$[φ^k
, [φ, ψ]] = 0 ∀k ∈ N$
and
$[φ
^k
, ψ] = 0$.
Here, $φ
k$ denotes the composition of $φ$ k-times with itself.

Comment: That's fine, but you are also enjoined to prove $A^{k+1}B-BA^{k+1}=0$ for $k\ge1$.

Comment: Why do we have to show that